# Non-linear HJB PDE using Fipy, PDE translation

Tags: python, pde, fipy

I'm trying to solve a non-linear PDE HJB equation using FiPy, but i have some difficulties translating the PDE into the proper FiPy syntax:

I tried something like : 
eqX = TransientTerm() == -DiffusionTerm(coeff=1) + (phi.faceGrad * phi.faceGrad)
and It doesn't work because of the square of the gradient

My equation: (du/dt = - \delta u + ||\grad(u)||^2)

Does FiPy allow to solve this kind of equations? if not is there a package or a way to solve it using finite difference ? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to recast the final term to be a diffusion term and a source term so that the equation can be rewritten as,

```
eqn = TransientTerm() = DiffusionTerm(u - 1) - u * u.faceGrad.divergence
```

That won't give an error, but might not be very stable

Comment: `phi.grad.dot(phi.grad)` is another possibility